# Honda Civic won't start (2017)

Tags: honda, battery, starting, civic

I have a push button start. When I push it the car doesn't start. Brake pedal seems hard to push. Warning lights flash - I.e. brake system, stability control, restraint system, electric power steering control, etc. No power at all. It seems I can't even lock the car with the remote key.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check the battery voltage ... I'd bet it is low for whatever reason.

Comment: No. It may just be it needs charged. It might have been discharged down to a level which won't allow the car to start. Something like leaving a dome light on in the car overnight would do it. First check the voltage. If it is below 12vdc, it probably needs charged. If you get it charged then it still doesn't want to start, it could mean the battery. Most manufacturers batteries last about five years. Yours should still be in the "good" range, though this doesn't automatically negate replacement.

Comment: Replaced battery. Does anyone know how to reset the warning indicators such as tire pressure low and ESC light?

Comment: There should be an ESC control somewhere, perhaps an actual button, which needs to be pressed. As for tire warning, you should be able to navigate through the settings and find something like "tire pressures all OK". Of course, they must *be* OK, some vehicles don't have actual pressure sensors and rely on you having checked the tires at an air pump. In the past I have had other warnings (such as steering), which seem to reset themselves when I drive the car.